# How to insert value into foreign key in SQL server? (Avoid the duplicate key.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I create two table. They connected by primary key and foreign key. When I insert new values, it said cannot insert duplicate key in object. Here are my tables

```
create table person (
sinNum int primary key not null,
gender varchar(6) not null check (gender in ('male','female')) default 'female',
age int not null check (age>=18 and age<=100),
emailAddr varchar (50) not null,
phoneNum int not null,  
)


create table employee (
empId int identity (1,1) unique,
lastName varchar (30) not null,
firstName varchar (30) not null,
sinNum int unique foreign key references person (sinNum),
departmentId int foreign key references department (departmentId), 
position varchar (20) not null check (position in ('clerk','assistant','supervisor','manager','director','president')) default'clerk',
baseSalary float not null
)
```

Here are my insert statements

```
insert into person (sinNum,gender,age,emailAddr, phoneNum) values (333, 
'female', 24, 'dds', 2121)

insert into employee(lastName,firstName, sinNum, departmentId, 
position,baseSalary) values ('Snow','John',333,20,'clerk',4000)
```

Here are the error messages

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__person__228E26BE3A9512B2'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.person'. The duplicate key
>   value is (333).

Can anyone show me the way please? Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to insert '333' again to `dbo.person`? You cannot do this since its a primary key voilation. Field with Primary key cannot have redundant data.

Comment: How may I suppose to do with this voilation? Because I need the employee and person can only match by the sinNum.

Comment: @Jeffery If person.sisNum needs to be unique you could consider using the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) to upsert the record instead of trying to insert a duplicate.

Comment: There's already a person with sinNum 333. Try to query `SELECT * FROM person WHERE sinNum = 333`.  If it returns a record, then you know that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set sinNum as identity. Make it auto incremented and then change your insert query as below.

```
insert into person (sinNum,gender,age,emailAddr, phoneNum) values ((SELECT ISNULL(MAX(sinNum)+1,0) FROM person WITH(SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)), 
'female', 24, 'dds', 2121)
```

You can use simpler version also, but it doesn't guarantee concurrency:

```
insert into person (sinNum,gender,age,emailAddr, phoneNum) values (NULL, 
'female', 24, 'dds', 2121)
```

Comment: sinNum is randomly given. It can not be automatically assigned.

Comment: @Jeffery Then there is no point specifying it as `PrimaryKey`. Remove the PrimaryKey.

Answer (score 0):

Since sinNum is your primary key, if you try to `INSERT` a new row containing the same value it will reject you.

Just use the following query to delete the rows before adding it again.

```
DELETE FROM person WHERE sinNum = 333;
```

You can also update/merge the row or simply not add it, since you have done it already.

Answer (score 0):

As the column 'sinum' is primary key, you can't define it explicitly.

So please have a try with below.

```
Insert into person (gender,age,emailAddr, phoneNum) values ( 'female', 24, 'dds', 2121)

Declare @sinnum=IDENT_CURRENT('Person')

If @@error=0

Insert into employee(lastName,firstName, sinnum, departmentId, position,baseSalary) values ('Snow','John',@sinnum,20,'clerk',4000)
```

Ident_current will save the last inserted primary key value in the mentioned table. Saving that value in a temporary variable, inorder to use the same value as FK in the employee table.

@@error used here to ensure insert on employee table only on successful insert made in person table.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that your insert on Person table is violating the primary key constraint. So we can use this exception as an antidote.

You can make use of **Try-Catch** statement and can implement your further logic in the catch block.

```
/* You an use @output parameter too */
Declare @output bit=1

BEGIN TRY
    insert into person (sinNum,gender,age,emailAddr, phoneNum) values (333, 
    'female', 24, 'dds', 2121)

    insert into employee(lastName,firstName, sinNum, departmentId, 
    position,baseSalary) values ('Snow','John',333,20,'clerk',4000)

    print 'Record inserted in both table'

set @output=1
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 if error_message() like 'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint%'
    Begin

    /* Do whatever you like to do here */
    /* You can delete the existing record if you want */

     print 'Record already exists is Person table' --just the intimation
     set @output=0

    End

 else
    print 'other exception'       --just the intimation

END CATCH
```

*You can delete the existing record in catch block or can make new transaction using @output variable.*. Hope it works for you.